# Can't open a windows network location in my homegroup from JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

i am trying to open a jupyter notebook saved on another machine.
That machine is on the same windows homegroup, i can access and modify it's files easily using the windows explorer.
But i can't find a way to make JupyterLab recognize the adress correctly.
For example the jupyter notebooks i want are located on the user AGUXSURFACEA, so in explorer i can type \AGUXSURFACEA and i can access the files.
I cannot use this path at all in JupyterLab, when i click on "Open from path" i never imagine an adress that could make it work.
Sublimetext on the other hand (i know is a text editor has nothing to do) can recognize this kind of adress.
I would apreciate any help.

SOLUTION:
Found a solution. Made a vbs script to simultaneously mount the network path to a drive letter, and then opening jupyter lab.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /K net use M: \\AGUXSURFACEA\Programacion & cd /d M:\ & Dir & jupyter lab"
oShell.Run Command,0,True
```

The command "net use" will mount the network path you want, i assigned the letter M to it on this case, you can assign the letter you want.

Comment: Do you mean open the file in Python code? Or actually show in the file tree of jupyterlab? The first has nothing to do with jupyter

Comment: No. I want the application called "JupyterLab" be able to open saved jupyter notebooks (.ipynb extension), that are located on the disk of another user on a Windows homegroup. Yes i want these remote files to show in the tree of jupyterlab, and edit them from this other computer.

Comment: The homegroup files are technically resolvable by a filesystem path, so have you tried to start `jupyterlab --notebook-dir [path]`? Otherwise, sublime and other text editors are using your OS file explorer, not Javascript/Python to list files on your machine. Alternatively, I think NFS or Samba share would work better

Comment: Oh ok. Then probably i don't know how to type a path that is in my homegroup. As an example i am trying this:
jupyterlab --notebook-dir \\AGUXSURFACEA\Programacion\Notebook3.ipynb
That is absolutely not working, i am trying tu figure out how to write the networks paths correctly.